# Glide listener getting called when it shouldn't be

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-glide

I have an app which uses **Firebase**. When a user logs in, an activity will check if user data is present in the **Firestore database** and get them to the app if it is present.

This is the code for that (this is `OnCreate`)

```java
FirebaseFirestore
        .getInstance()
        .document("users/" + uID)
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (task.getResult().exists()) {
                        DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult();
                        name.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("name"));
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Glide
                            .with(SetUserData.this)
                            .load(FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("profile_images/" + uID))
                            .skipMemoryCache(true)
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                            .error(R.drawable.default_user_icon)
                            .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                    if (e.getRootCauses().size() == 1 && e.getRootCauses().get(0) instanceof StorageException) {
                                        if (((StorageException) e.getRootCauses().get(0)).getErrorCode() == StorageException.ERROR_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND) {
                                            Toast.makeText(SetUserData.this, "testing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            progressHUD.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(SetUserData.this, "Some error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        Log.e("Glide Exception", e.getMessage());
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                    return false;
                                }

                                @Override
                                public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    progressHUD.dismiss();
                                    return false;
                                }
                        }).into(imageView);
                    }
                    else {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        progressHUD.dismiss();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(SetUserData.this, "Some error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e("Firestore error", task.getException().getMessage());
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }
    );
```

I have an activity where when I press an `ImageView`, an [image cropping tool is invoked](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper). This is the code for the `setOnClickListener()` listener:

```java
imageView.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CropImage
                    .activity()
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .start(SetUserData.this); //get image and crop - custom library
        }
    }
);
```

And this is the `onActivityResult()` method:

```java
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            imageUri = result.getUri();
            try {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
            result.getError().printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Some error has occurred, please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Every time I try to set an image in the `ImageView` the `onLoadFailed` method of the **Glide** `listener()` gets executed and I have no idea how or why, all I know is that it shouldn't. I know that it gets executed because of the `toast()` I put in that method. The code **above** the **Glide** statement and **below** **Firestore** statement does **NOT** get executed, only the Glide `listener()` method. [Video link](https://youtu.be/NFg5RD5CJqs)

I have spent 2 days on this and it's driving me crazy, any idea why this is happening?

Comment: can you not click on profile button for maybe 30 seconds and see if toast is visible anyways. My guess is this might not have happened because of your code but Firebase listener getting called late.

Comment: @RahulKumar the code gets normally executed at the start of the activity and again if I choose a profile picture. It's not delayed.